# dojo function with multiple contexts

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dojo, dom-events

I have a `dojo` class created with `dojo/_base/declare` that includes an `onClickHandler`.  This handler is used by a `dijit/form/Button` to work with data stored within the class.  I need the handler to be able to reference both the `Button` that triggered the event and the instance of the class to which the handler belongs.

For example, below is the first part of the handler function from the class:

```
drawToolClick : function(evt) {

    this.drawingtoolbar.deactivate(); // Here `this` should represent the instance of my class

    var parent = this.getParent(); // Here `this` should represent the button that was clicked
```

I know that I obviously can't use `this` to represent both, but when I use `dojo/_base/lang` to `hitch` my class instance to the function, I do not know which button was clicked (I have multiple buttons using the same handler because they represent an `enum`).  If I leave out the `hitch` `this` references the button that was clicked, but I don't know how to get the instance of the class that the handler is part of.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the class? If it's a UI class then can you *subclass* `Button` instead? If it's *model* data, then are you sure a click handler should be attached to it, as a click handler is UI.

Comment: This class is basically all of the functions and variables I had originally written in non-AMD style that I have converted to AMD by wrapping it into a class.  I wouldn't say it follows any specific pattern meant to separate out UI from data from functionality (i.e. MVC).  My application is a web mapping application, so this class represents all the code needed to work with the mapping API I am using.  That is why I have placed the `onclick` handlers in this class, because the code in the handler manipulates the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured this out.  I simply added a variable `var self;` in my module where the class is defined before the `declare` statement.  Then, in my class `constructor` function I added `self = this;`.

Then in my `onclick` handler I use `this` to reference the button that was clicked and I use `self` to reference the class instance.

This seems to work alright.